# Java: Cannot find symbol - variable faceValue

Tags: java

I am making a program that prints the color of the cube and the number of sides it has, and then rolls the dice 10 times to print the numbers.
I am having a problem with for loop that is supposed to roll the dice. When I compile, it has an error saying that it cannot find symbol - variable faceValue. I defined faceValue but it still says it cannot find the symbol. This is my runner code.

```
public class ProbilityCubeRunner
{
    private String faceValue;
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
       ProbilityCube cube1 = new ProbilityCube ("yellow", 10);
       System.out.println(cube1);
       int sides1 = cube1.sides;

       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
        int x = 1+(int)(Math.random()*sides1);
         if(i<9)
        {
           faceValue = faceValue + x + ",";
        }
         else
        {
           faceValue = faceValue + x;
        }
       }
       System.out.println(faceValue);

       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

How do I define the symbol string variable faceValue?

Comment: non static variables cannot be accessed from static method.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: `private static String faceValue;` use this instead of `private String faceValue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `faceValue` should be static. You cannot access non-static variables from a static method. Since your main method is a static one. The variable faceValue you are accessing from it should also be static.

Change the declaration if faveValue as follows.

```
private static String faceValue;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: You can accept the answer if you find it helpful. Cheers.!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access it from the static context. Make it static or create an instance of Main class. It depends on your business logic.

So you should either declare it like:

```
private static String faceValue;
```

or leave it as is and call via the instance:

```
Main m = new Main(); //in your main method
m.faceValue = ...
```